# How to provide credentials, third party API keys, etc, to an Auto-GPT session?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, autogpt

I'm experimenting with getting Auto-GPT to perform various tasks, one of which was to plot a road driving route with several "via" waypoints.  This is fairly easy to do in Google Maps so I wanted to see how the AI would handle it.

It started well and soon worked out that it needed to use Google Maps, and found the correct API - but then completely failed to obtain and use an API key.  Instead it would run a script with the sample "api-key=your-key-here" in the data, which of course failed.  It would parse the result, detect that it needed a valid API key, state that it was going to obtain one - and then fail to do so and repeat the same error.  This would continue in an endless loop until I halted the session.

It's probably a good thing that it can't yet auto sign itself up for random API keys, however, is there any way I can pass it keys that I have already obtained for accounts that I own (on any system, not just Google Maps), so that it can then use them to obtain results?

I've tried googling for instances of this problem but all that comes up is multiple copies of instructions for obtaining an OpenAI paid account and API key, which I already have, the issue is enabling the agent to be aware of and use third party API keys.